# Sharing Multi-dimensional Arrays across different forms in VB

Tags: vb.net, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a very simple 2D array, it holds a list of song titles, their genre, and their runtime.

frmMain loads the array from a text file and allows me to manipulate it and boil it down to a desired (implicitly sized) playlist. i want to THEN pass that playlist array to a second form, frmPlaylist

The problem i'm running into....When frmPLaylist calls the Property from frmMain I receive an error that VB cannot convert the string value to a two dimensional array.

**Simplified**...frmPlaylist is all locked and ready to receive a 2D array, but frmMain seems to only be sending a single string variable.

Here's the code i'm working with if it helps.

on frmMain

```
Public ReadOnly Property PlaylistOut() As String
        Get
            Return mstrTimedPlaylist(,)
        End Get
    End Property
```

on frmPLaylist

```
  mstrTimedPlaylist2 = frmMain.PlaylistOut()
```

Comment: And `mstrTimedPlaylist` is declared as?..

Comment: Private mstrTimedPlaylist(,) As String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public ReadOnly Property PlaylistOut() As String(,)
    Get
        Return mstrTimedPlaylist
    End Get
End Property
```